# Is the 'weapon' tag a synonym of the 'weapons' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonymization

The [weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) tag is not currently a synonym of the [weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag. The tag synonym guidelines state that

> If you know of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for [a] tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

Based on that, it seems like the [weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) is a good fit to be a synonym of [weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks! [weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon) (2 questions) has now been made a synonym of the much-more-used [weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag.